# How to flash bottom of exterior walls that butt up against cement curb

Tags: exterior, flashing

Our home has a cement curb on the rear portion of the house that butts up against the exterior sheathing. There is approximately a 1” gap between the sheathing and the curb.

What is the best way to flash this area to prevent water from entering into this gap?

[image]

Comment: would z flashing like this be appropriate here? https://www.lowes.com/pd/Window-and-Door-Cap-1-25-in-x-120-in-x-1-56-in-Aluminum-Z-Flashing/5001929797

Comment: Z or L flashing leaving a 1/4" gap between curb and 1/4" gap above the flashing kickout for the siding to start.

Comment: @redlude97 why a quarter inch gap between the flashing and the curb?

Comment: just found this video which looks to be a pretty good approach https://youtu.be/pieezQpcDsg

Comment: mostly to prevent water getting trapped there. You can caulk the gap